# Do calls to the Google Drive Changes feed count against API quota?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have an application that needs to stay in sync with google drive.  To that end, I'm using the Changes feed that is described on [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes).

I know the idea is to poll the changes feed so that I don't have to request a list of files and do a comparison. Right now I have it set to query every 30 seconds, and initiate a sync operation when the latest change number is updated.  But, to make the application feel a little more responsive, I would like to query API more frequently (but still initiate a sync only when necessary)

Given that, I was wondering if requests against the Changes feed count toward the API quota?  I don't want to query more frequently if it's going to double my quota consumption rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like requests to the changes API **do** count toward the quota.  I found the Reports section in the cloud console.  It gives a detailed breakdown of requests by user, location, method, and more.  Looking through the methods, I found that `drive.changes.list` accounts for the majority of my usage.

It's unfortunate, but better than burning through the quota with multiple calls to get the status of every file.